# One touch event puts all child views into pressed state

Tags: android, events, view, touch

Doubtless this is caused by my decidedly unorthodox layout - I have buttons in a LinearLayout in an Activity which is placed by an ActivityGroup into a Gallery. The ActivityGroup is also the adapter implementation and the over-all effect is full-screen sliding, snapping panels.

This is working (a treat, actually) except that a touch event on the parent layout puts all the buttons into the pressed state (and any release removes the state). A touch on an individual button is only delivered to that button.

The buttons are not receiving any events, they're only changing state.

Have I done something obviously wrong? Is this a known bug and is there a work-around?

Any insights would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As obscure as this problem is its solution may be of use to someone else, so I'll answer my own question.

As mentioned, I'm (mis)using the Gallery to provide a slidey-panel à la iPhone. I do this by returning the top level window of an Activity when the Gallery asks its Adapter implementation for a view.

Typical use of a Gallery would result in small Views to which it's desirable for the press event to be applied - it's more like a button then it is a panel. Our use means that there are many buttons in a single view and we don't want the press event to ever be applied globally.

So the work-around was very easy. I extended Gallery and deliberately broke pointToPosition(int x, int y), returning INVALID_POSITION every time. The Gallery still does everything else expected of it but skips trying to apply the touch down event to any elements but itself (to prepare itself to scroll or fling).

I hope this is of value to someone.

Comment: That saved me a lot of time indeed, thx! But question is: If the Gallery is not supposed to be used for such things, what is?

Comment: Good question. In fact so far as I know there isn't really a slidey panel corresponding to that of iPhone apart from the Gallery, but from its name and the above-mentioned practice of applying touch events to all child views, I posited that this use was at any rate not anticipated by those who wrote it.
Having said that now this issue is fixed it's doing the job very well. I'm glad the post was of use to you.